# SAS proc import excel when tab name has dollar sign

Tags: excel, import, sas

Hi I have an excel file with 2 sheets that have dollar sign in their sheet names. I am not allowed to change the sheet names. I have tried to use "range" it does not work. Is there a way to read in these two sheets? Thank you!

```
proc import datafile = "&input.\filename.xlsx"
    out = raw
    DBMS = xlsx replace;
    range="name with $ sign$A1:F10";
run;
```

Comment: Try a libname connection using XLSX, run a proc contents to see how SAS expects it to be formatted and use that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (`SAS 9.4M2`) it works fine:

```
proc import datafile="&input.\filename.xlsx" out=raw dbms=xlsx replace;
/* method 1 */
    sheet="name with $ sign";
/* method 2 */
    range="'name with $ sign'$A1:F10";
run;
```